# WebGL texImage2D parameters

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am trying to load an image file into my webGL code and create a texture out of it but while loading the image i get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': 
>   parameter 9 is not of type 'ArrayBufferView'.
>       at Image. (app.js:13)

```
 var image = new Image();
 image.src = "./js-logo.png";
 image.addEventListener("load", function(){
     gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
     gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 10, 10, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
     gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

See [WebGL Specification - 5.14 The WebGL context](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14):

> ```
> [...]
> void texImage2D(GLenum target, GLint level, GLint internalformat,
>                 GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLint border, GLenum format,
>                 GLenum type, [AllowShared] ArrayBufferView? pixels);
> void texImage2D(GLenum target, GLint level, GLint internalformat,
>                 GLenum format, GLenum type, TexImageSource source); // May throw DOMException
> ```

Since image is `image` is a `TexImageSource` it has to be

<s>`gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 10, 10, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);`</s>
`gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);`

Note, the size of the bitmap is encode int the `image` object.

---

Further you should set the texture filtering parameters:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "./js-logo.png";
image.addEventListener("load", function(){
     gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
     gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 10, 10, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
     gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR );
     gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
     gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
 });
```

Comment: Yes, I did get a DOMException saying that the image has cross-origin data and may not be loaded even tho i am not sure what it means, should i try with a different image?

Comment: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The image element contains cross-origin data, and may not be loaded.(even tho I added the setAttribute function)

Comment: @ПламенЦанев You have to set `image.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');` before `image.src = "./js-logo.png";`

Comment: @ПламенЦанев Read [WebGL Fundamentals: WebGL - Cross Origin Images](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cors-permission.html) for further information (excellent article).

Comment: The article was useful indeed and I did what it says, making the origin equal to "" when the image isnt from the same domain and gave me new errors:
TTP-Based Public Key Pinning is deprecated. Chrome 69 and later will ignore HPKP response headers. (Host: c1.staticflickr.com)
Image (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):23
(index):1 [.WebGL-000002BCF82EBA50]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glGenerateMipmap: Can not generate mips
255[.WebGL-000002BCF82EBA50]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.

Comment: @ПламенЦанев Set the minifying and magnification function. The side length of the texture has to be power of 2, for WebGL 1.0 context.